# Как выделить только никнейм, все остальное убрать

Tags: java

У меня есть `event.getMessage()` он даёт сообщение, вот например такое
`§6Krolations§7 просит телепортироваться к Вам.§7§l [§2§l?§7§l]§7§l [§c§l?§7§l]`
Как мне из этого сообщения выделить только никнейм `Krolations`? Он может быть разной длины, но всё же как его только получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря, что известно о формате вашей строчки. Например, `event.getMessage().split("§.")[1]` сработает в вашем случае. (Бьем строку на подстроки, где разделителем является символ § плюс следующий за ним, и берем вторую подстроку.) Так `"§6Krolations§7 просит телепортироваться к Вам.§7§l [§2§l?§7§l]§7§l [§c§l?§7§l]".split("§.")[1]` будет давть "Krolations"